# Changing application variable in thread not giving correct result

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, global-variables

I made simple web page. when its called with querystring it increases the application variable. after 3 seconds, when thread finishes variable decreases.

problem is, when I open 2 explorer page (or mozilla) and call page from one and get results from other, everything is fine. but when I use multthreaded test application make 200 or more calls, numbers don't come back to zero. it never stays in same number like 240 or 20.. everytime its different but not zero.

page_load event prepared to automatize process. my multiple thread application calls this page like `http://localhost:4444/test.aspx?i=anything`  so page automaticallu adds 1 to variable "x" and starts thread. variable supposed to minus 1 after 3 seconds and total should become zero. but not ???

important: when I use 1 thread in my test application to call this web page it works "mostly" fine. for example it goes up to 680 and returns back to zero, sometimes. If I use 2 threads to call page then results are "always" inconsistent.

funny  thing is instead of using application variable if I use sql server and keep variable there and increase/decrease with

```
UPDATE test SET count=count + 1
UPDATE test SET count=count - 1
```

I see no problem even with 20 simultaneous connection.

any suggestions ?

```
Partial Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim _resetEvent As New AutoResetEvent(False)
    Protected Sub cmdWriteVariable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdWriteVariable.Click
        Response.Write(Application("x").ToString)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub cmdIncreaseValue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdIncreaseValue.Click
        If Application("x") Is Nothing Then Application("x") = 0
        Application.Lock()
        Application("x") = CInt(Application("x").ToString) + 1
        Application.UnLock()
        Response.Write(Application("x").ToString)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Async_start()
        Dim workerObject As New myTestAsyncClass(_resetEvent)
        workerObject.ad = "anyname"
        Dim ctx As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
        Dim workerThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub()
                                                           HttpContext.Current = ctx
                                                           workerObject.DoWork2(ctx)
                                                       End Sub))
        workerThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub cmdReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdReset.Click
        Application("x") = 0
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Application("x") Is Nothing Then Application("x") = 0

        If Request.QueryString("i") IsNot Nothing Then
            Application.Lock()
            Application("x") = CInt(Application("x").ToString) + 1
            Application.UnLock()
            Async_start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the thread class:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading

Public Class myTestAsyncClass

    Dim _resetEvent As AutoResetEvent = Nothing
    Public ad As String

    Public Sub New(resetEvent As AutoResetEvent)
        _resetEvent = resetEvent
    End Sub
    Public Sub DoWork2(state As Object)
        Try
            Dim context As HttpContext = TryCast(state, HttpContext)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
            Dim x As Integer = CInt(context.Application("x").ToString)
            x = x - 1
            context.Application.Lock()
            context.Application("x") = x.ToString
            context.Application.UnLock()
        Finally
            _resetEvent.[Set]()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

and aspx page just in case: its simple 3 buttons. write variable, reset to zero and increase 1. open 2 explorer, click increase multiple times and from other explorer click write variable button. you'll see its working fine. increses to, lets say 10 and after 3 seconds variable comes to zero.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Async="true" Inherits="test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdIncreaseValue" runat="server" Text="increasevalue" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdWriteVariable" runat="server" Text="write app variable" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdReset" runat="server" Text="set varable to 0" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, I believe I found it here:

I hope someday it helps someone.

best..

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358448/why-my-httpcontext-application-variable-cannot-be-access-through-different-actio
```

says:

```
Disadvantages of Application State:

Application scope The scope of application state can also be a disadvantage. 
Variables stored in application state are global only to the particular process the 
application is running in, and each application process can have different values. 
Therefore, you cannot rely on application state to store unique values or update global
counters in Web-garden and Web-farm server configurations.
```